# Asynchronously constructing a producer

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a case where I want to construct a `ReceiveChannel` using `produce`, asynchronously, but it's hanging. Here's a simplified example:

```
runBlocking {
    val deferredChannel = async {
        produce<String> { send("foo") }
    }

    val channel = deferredChannel.await()

    println("Got channel")

    val value = channel.receive()

    println("Got value $value")
}
```

*Neither* `println` is hit. It's plausible that there's some kind of coroutine deadlock going on, but I'm not not clear where/how.

How can I produce a `ReceiveChannel` asynchronously?

Edit: It works if I change `produce` to `produce(capacity = 1)`, but why is that? Shouldn't the `await()` succeed, at least, regardless of the producer's capacity? And what if I want to keep capacity=0?

Comment: Changing `async` to `async(context = newSingleThreadContext("producer"))` doesn't appear to have any impact.

Comment: `It works if I change produce to produce(capacity = 1)` -- only because you produce just one element. In a production case it will keep producing until it fills the buffer.

Comment: If I were expecting `async {` to behave like `thread {`, it shouldn't matter what I put inside the block -- it'll execute regardless. But that's not happening here, because of some disconnect in my understanding.

Comment: It does behave like `thread {` until you `await()` on the result, which has no equivalent in `thread {`, but is comparable to `executor.submit(task).get()`, which blocks the same way because you create a deadlock where the submitted task is waiting for you to accept its item, but you don't accept it until it has completed.

Answer (score 1):

> It works if I change produce to produce(capacity = 1), but why is that? Shouldn't the await() succeed, at least, regardless of the producer's capacity?

Checking the [docs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/produce.html) on the `produce()` method you call, and specifically the [docs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-channel/index.html) on the capacity parameter and `Channel` we have (emphasis mine):

> **When capacity is 0** – it creates RendezvousChannel. **This channel does not have any buffer at all**. An **element is transferred from sender to receiver only when send and receive invocations meet in time** (rendezvous), so **send suspends until another coroutine invokes receive** and receive suspends until another coroutine invokes send.

This could be the reason why it's hanging. You are calling `send` on your `async` thread and then `await` for it... however, as the docs say, no other co-routine has invoked `receive` yet... so it will suspend until that happens and in this case it hangs.

Checking that same link on Channel, we also see why giving it a number greater than 0 solves this (emphasis mine):

> **When capacity is positive**, but less than UNLIMITED – it creates array-based channel with given capacity. This channel has an array buffer of a fixed capacity. **Sender suspends only when buffer is full and receiver suspends only when buffer is empty**.